# Oracle 10g- exporting and importing Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I need a command for importing a table for the following scenario.

I have a table EMPLOYEE in server A. I am exporting the Table.

I have another table PDATA(having same structure of EMPLOYEE table) in server B.

I need to import the records from EMPLOYEE table(server A) into PDATA table(server B).

I am using Oracle 10g. Please advise.

Comment: Are there BLOB columns in those tables?

Comment: You have to consider if the data from table EMPLOYEE may violate the constraints in table PDATA.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.  I am going to assume that you don't have any binary data and that the tables aren't absurdly large.  We also don't know what type of access you have to either server.

1. You could use a tool, such as TOAD, to either export to csv or create insert statements.  Then execute those on the second server.
2. You could use PL/SQL and the UTL_FILE library to dump the contents of the table to a csv file.  Then mount the csv file as an external table and select into your new table.
3. If you have the appropriate permissions and the machines can physically see each other you can setup a database link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm Once the link is created, you can select from one table into the other.
4. If you are a DBA then you can use the Export utility, which will export the table into a binary format that can be imported elsewhere.

Comment: I'd try the database link method first.